# Prevent tap event on UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.106 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=delayed:, target=)>>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.107 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=)>>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.108 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=oneFingerTripleTap:, target=)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 3>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.108 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=oneFingerDoubleTap:, target=)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 2>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.109 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=twoFingerSingleTap:, target=)>; numberOfTouchesRequired = 2>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.123 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=tapAndAHalf:, target=)>>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.124 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=twoFingerRangedSelectGesture:, target=)>>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.124 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=oneFingerTap:, target=)>>
>
> 2012-02-21 11:59:18.129 textView[20977:fe03] ; target= <(action=loupeGesture:, target=)>>

Above the list of gestureRecogniser on UITextView. I need to prevent event: twoFingerSingleTap on UITextView, but only this event. there is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *g in myTextView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    if ([g isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        if (([(UITapGestureRecognizer *)g numberOfTouchesRequired] == 2) && ([(UITapGestureRecognizer *)g numberOfTapsRequired] == 1))
        {
            [g setEnabled: NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kyr Dunenkoff: i agree your answer is more educational. +1 for that. but we all have learned something also from ready made code.

Answer (score 4):

`UITextView`, as any other subclass of `UIView`, has `gestureRecognizers` property, which contains an NSArray of all gesture recognizers attached to a view. Enumerate this array, find recognizer you're looking for and disable it.

Comment: tks but how to enumerate this array??

Comment: Have you at least tried to read documentation? Fast enumeration - [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html]. To disable something - `[object setEnabled:NO];`