# UITextTapRecongnizer disable action twoFingerSingleTap on UITextView but not other gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I need to disable the action twoFingerSingleTap from the class UITextTapRecongnizer on UITextView **when the keyboard is up** to make another function with the same gesture.

someone has an idea??

tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a followup from your other question: [Prevent tap event on UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378355/prevent-tap-event-on-uitextview)

Instead of disabling that gesture recogniser you could try 'hijcaking' it.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *g in myTextView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    if ([g isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        if (([(UITapGestureRecognizer *)g numberOfTouchesRequired] == 2) && ([(UITapGestureRecognizer *)g numberOfTapsRequired] == 1))
        {
          //[g setEnabled: NO]; this was for disabling
          [g removeTarget:nil action:nil]; //this removes all targets and actions (documentation!)
          [g addTarget: self action:@selector(myHandler:)];
        }
    }
}

- (void)myHandler:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    NSLog (@"success...");
    //do your stuff
}
```

EDIT: if this (according to your edited question) stops working when keyboard shows up then try this: override `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` method of your `textViewDelegate` and put the same code inside.

Comment: @benhi: That's actually a completely other question - the qustion posted here was already answered.

Comment: @benhi: revised my answer - it should work with your new question